# Pasar datos de un JSON a una función en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

¿Cómo puedo pasar datos de un archivo JSON a una variable en un documento con JavaScript?, mi JSON es el siguiente:

```
{
  "cotizadorcentrales": {
   "tarifaBase": 3218,
   "paginaImpar": 4007,
   "pagina3o5": 6307,
   "paginaUltima": 4007
  },
  "cotizadorregular": {
    "tarifaBase": 3218,
    "paginaImpar": 4007,
    "pagina3o5": 6307,
    "paginaUltima": 4007
  },
  "cotizadorregular_2014_printprueba": {
    "tarifaBase": 3218,
    "paginaImpar": 4007,
    "pagina3o5": 6307,
    "paginaUltima": 4007
  }
}
```

Y necesito que una variable en JavaScript guarde el valor de `tarifaBase` y lo muestre en pantalla.

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué haz intentado hacer?...

Comment: Hola Jose, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
De paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Te recomiendo repasar sobre [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), saludos.

Comment: Vamos por partes, el Json donde lo tienes?? en un archivo separado?

Comment: Hola, cuando te refieres a _mostrar en pantalla_ te refieres a algo así? https://jsfiddle.net/9kfudzgm/

Comment: El json lo tengo en un archivo separado, y ahorita utilize el metodo fetch, correcto, pero no se como guardar esos valores en una variable en el script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de esta forma con [**For in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), creo que esto es lo que buscas.

Al final obtienes un `Array` con los valores de `tarifaBase` de todos los objetos que contenga el `json`

```
const tarifaBases = []

fetch('./cotizador.json') 
    .then((response) => response.json()) 
    .then((json) => {
        for (const key in json) {
            const element = json[key];
            tarifaBases.push(element.tarifaBase)
        }
    })

console.log(tarifaBases)
```

***SALIDA***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Correcto, si, una vez que ya tengo los datos, como puedo guardar ese 3218 en una variable dentro de un script.

Comment: La tarifaBase siempre va a ser la misma?, o quieres que por cada objeto (`cotizadorCentrales,...`) exista una variable con su tarifaBase.

Comment: Que cada objeto tenga su tarifa base.

Comment: Ese script del que hablas de que trata?, lo digo porque dependiendo de cuál sea su función quizás no sea necesario sacar los valores del array

Comment: Es poder cambiar los valores de tarifaBase desde el json para que los cache el script y poderlos mostrar, eso ya lo pude realizar gracias a tu ayuda, lo unico que me falta es como puedo hacer para que cada objeto tenga tenga su propia tarifaBase y mostrarla. tarifaBases.push(element.cotizadorcentrales.tarifaBase)  ????